# Creating users in AWS SSO group using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, boto3

I have used boto3 pretty much but never used it for accessing AWS SSO. It is the first time I am going to work on AWS SSO, So pretty new to this. I want to create a user in AWS SSO GROUP, but I could not find any method in [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sso-admin.html). Is there any way I can achieve this?

I know this is a very broad question, so even a direction where to look or any minor help will also be appreciated.

I have recently came across [SCIM AP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/developerguide/createuser.html)I, Any idea how I can use it to create user using that ?

Comment: AWS SSO is used to link to an identity system (eg Active Directory). Users would be created in the identity system and then AWS SSO can be used to let them access AWS.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes right but we can also create users and give them access to aws accounts using SSO right? I want to perform that. Any idea how I can achieve that? Thanks for responding

Comment: You have to integrate the AWS SSO with an AD, then users/groups from the AD can be synced with AWS SSO and you can assign those users/groups that are now visible in AWS SSO to the specific accounts, you also need permission sets to define access scope.

Comment: @StefanosAsl. hey thanks for responding, is there any way I can sync it using boto3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AWS SSO Single Sign-on to create an identity store(boto3 identity store) and users/groups(boto3 sso-admin), also check out permission sets again in SSO Signle Sign-On, AWS gives you several premade ones though.

At this point you should have a user/group now you use the SSO service to assign the user/group to the account(boto3 create_account_assignment) and you also need to attach the permission set to the user/group you just attached to the account, think of it having two baskets one with permission sets and one with users/groups you pick one item from each basket and you assign them together to your account using the AWS SSO service

Comment: Hey thank you so much, this will definitely help. Could you please provide a code snippet for listing the users in a group? also, creating a user and assigning a group to him if possible?

Comment: Check here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/109 , currently AWS does not support this functionality via boto3 but you can find workarounds in there.

Comment: Cool, I will look into it thanks. They still have not come up w this functionality? so as of now this is not possible?

Comment: Which role policy i can add to aws lambda to  access SSO and do list operations ?

Comment: you need to add actions, 'identitystore:ListUsers' and 'identitystore:ListGroups' in your lambda role. About creating users/groups this functionality should be decoupled from this lambda, so I would have a lambda that assigns groups and permissions sets to accounts and another 'script'  maybe not doable with lambda that takes care of creating users and groups in my SSO identity store

Comment: hey any idead how i can use [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/developerguide/getuser.html) to get data?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/developerguide/what-is-scim.html , not sure why you need this? It looks like an overkill for the use case you were describing.

Comment: I actually need to list users present in a group, so I was thinking of using this as there's no SDK that does this/